# Cannot view product pages - Invalid method Mage_Catalog_Model_Category::isComposite(Array

Tags: php, magento

Website working fine apart from viewing products, i just get the following errors

```
  Invalid method Mage_Catalog_Model_Category::isComposite(Array
  (
  )
  )
Trace:
  #0 /var/www/vhosts/MYTESTDOMAIN.co.uk/httpdocs/app/design/frontend/default/ma_enzo/template/magentothem/relatedslider/relatedslider.phtml(28): Varien_Object-&gt;__call('isComposite', Array)
  #1 /var/www/vhosts/MYTESTDOMAIN.co.uk/httpdocs/app/design/frontend/default/ma_enzo/template/magentothem/relatedslider/relatedslider.phtml(28): Mage_Catalog_Model_Category-&gt;isComposite()
  #2 /var/www/vhosts/MYTESTDOMAIN.co.uk/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include('/var/www/vhosts...')
  #3 /var/www/vhosts/MYTESTDOMAIN.co.uk/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template-&gt;fetchView('frontend/defaul...')
  #4 /var/www/vhosts/MYTESTDOMAIN.co.uk/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template-&gt;renderView()
  #5 /var/www/vhosts/MYTESTDOMAIN.co.uk/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(919): Mage_Core_Block_Template-&gt;_toHtml()
  #6 /var/www/vhosts/MYTESTDOMAIN.co.uk/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Text/List.php(43): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract-&gt;toHtml()
  #7 /var/www/vhosts/MYTESTDOMAIN.co.uk/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(919): Mage_Core_Block_Text_List-&gt;_toHtml()
  #8 /var/www/vhosts/MYTESTDOMAIN.co.uk/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(637): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract-&gt;toHtml()
  #9 /var/www/vhosts/MYTESTDOMAIN.co.uk/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(581): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract-&gt;_getChildHtml('right', true)
  #10 /var/www/vhosts/MYTESTDOMAIN.co.uk/httpdocs/app/design/frontend/default/ma_enzo/template/page/2columns-right.phtml(54): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract-&gt;getChildHtml('right')
  #11 /var/www/vhosts/MYTESTDOMAIN.co.uk/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include('/var/www/vhosts...')
  #12 /var/www/vhosts/MYTESTDOMAIN.co.uk/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template-&gt;fetchView('frontend/defaul...')
  #13 /var/www/vhosts/MYTESTDOMAIN.co.uk/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template-&gt;renderView()
  #14 /var/www/vhosts/MYTESTDOMAIN.co.uk/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(919): Mage_Core_Block_Template-&gt;_toHtml()
  #15 /var/www/vhosts/MYTESTDOMAIN.co.uk/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(555): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract-&gt;toHtml()
  #16 /var/www/vhosts/MYTESTDOMAIN.co.uk/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(390): Mage_Core_Model_Layout-&gt;getOutput()
  #17 /var/www/vhosts/MYTESTDOMAIN.co.uk/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Cms/Helper/Page.php(137): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action-&gt;renderLayout()
  #18 /var/www/vhosts/MYTESTDOMAIN.co.uk/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Cms/Helper/Page.php(52): Mage_Cms_Helper_Page-&gt;_renderPage(Object(Mage_Cms_IndexController), 'no-route')
  #19 /var/www/vhosts/MYTESTDOMAIN.co.uk/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Cms/controllers/IndexController.php(75): Mage_Cms_Helper_Page-&gt;renderPage(Object(Mage_Cms_IndexController), 'no-route')
  #20 /var/www/vhosts/MYTESTDOMAIN.co.uk/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Mage_Cms_IndexController-&gt;noRouteAction()
  #21 /var/www/vhosts/MYTESTDOMAIN.co.uk/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action-&gt;dispatch('noRoute')
  #22 /var/www/vhosts/MYTESTDOMAIN.co.uk/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard-&gt;match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
  #23 /var/www/vhosts/MYTESTDOMAIN.co.uk/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front-&gt;dispatch()
  #24 /var/www/vhosts/MYTESTDOMAIN.co.uk/httpdocs/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App-&gt;run(Array)
  #25 /var/www/vhosts/MYTESTDOMAIN.co.uk/httpdocs/index.php(89): Mage::run('', 'store')
  #26 {main}
```

any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I would look in the template file: app/design/frontend/default/ma_enzo/template/magentothem/relatedslider/relatedslider.phtml

It appears that your custom template is not referencing the Mage_Catalog_Model_Category correctly, this could be an empty array at the heart of the issue. If you want more help, you should include the template code.

Comment: Hi, i removed all related products and the pages work - i have now started relating products again and it still works - not sure why but it is solved - thanks for the response